# Change android APN proxy in code

Tags: android, proxy, provider, apn

I have a problem with access to my web services from some providers in my country because their APN proxys block outside traffic.
So, I would like to programmably change APN proxys on phones that have these proxys inserted (if proxy is set you can not access my website and web services but if you erase the proxy it works normally).

But every solution I find does not work on new android versions.
Is this possible to change or only temporarily use different APN settings for my HTTP request? Or if there is any other solution to this problem (on our server we have everything open)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible unless you application is a System app since Android 4.2